# Create Bootstrap Carousel slides with different hashtag URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to link to different slides in a bootstrap carousel from another page with no results.

Something like this:

```
<a href="services#slide2">Link to Slide2</a>
```

FYI, this is the standard bootstrap carousel:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried with this but it works only if it's the same page:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:goToSlide(3);">Go to slide #4</a>
<script>
function goToSlide(number) {
   $("#myCarousel").carousel(number);
}
</script>
```

Even a URL with different slides will do. Something like

```
mydomain.com/services#slide1
mydomain.com/services#slide2
mydomain.com/services#slide3
```

Comment: You mean you want to link to a different page and have that page start with a specific slide?

Comment: You'll have to call the same function on page load. And the function needs to check the URL for number. Get the number from the url and then pass the number to carousel.

Comment: I want the slides to have individual URLs perhaps with hashtags as mention in the last section of my question. How do I do that? I cant find any working example :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the same function on page load and after the carousel is ready. Get the number from the URL hash and pass it to the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var number = window.location.hash.replace(/^\D+/g, '');//Get the number
    goToSlide(number); //pass it on
});
```

Also you need to bind a hashchange event:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var number = window.location.hash.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    goToSlide(number);
});
```

And remove onclick from anchor tags

Comment: I added this but the URL remains the same. It is till mydomain.net/services with no hashtags added. Am I missing something? I want all the slides to have mydomain.net/services#slide1, mydomain.net/services#slide2, mydomain.net/services#slide3 etc

Comment: Check the href attribute in your links. Does it have proper URL? And is there any click handler bind to them which return false?

Comment: <a href="/services" onClick="javascript:goToSlide(2);">Go to slide #2</a> but this is not working. Please note that I'm trying this from another page. Not on the same page.

Comment: The URL doesn't change because the onclick function is executed when you click on the link. You need to remove one of them. Handle the redirection in the goToSlide.

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining it correctly. Please check the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/s8w0uLcr/